# Spring filter losing set variables after init function

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, java-8, spring-filter

I'm having a weird problem with a simple spring filter I'm using. In the `init` function I'm setting a variable `this.test = "TEST1234"` but for some reason when reaching then `doFilter` function this variable is reverted to null again.

**My filter:**

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    private String test;

    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) {
        this.test = "TEST1234";
        System.out.println("TEST: " + this.test);

    }

    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("TEST: " + this.test);
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(
                    new TestFilter(), 
                    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class
                );
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

init: `TEST: TEST1234`
doFilter: `TEST: null`

Why is this variable reverted to null? Am I missing something? Is it garbage collected?

I'm running my application on Java `1.8.0_171`

**Dependencies:**

- Spring boot starter web: `2.1.4.RELEASE`
- Spring security jwt: `1.0.10.RELEASE`
- Spring security oauth2: `2.2.1.RELEASE`
- Javax servlet: `2.5`

Comment: @Nikolas thanks for the answer, but I allready tried that. Removing `@Component` stops the `init` function from running at all. The `doFilter` still works though.

Comment: Right, my mistake. What package do you use the `Filter` from?

Comment: @Nikolas I'm using the `javax.servlet` package. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @Nikolas I removed the `@Override` while debugging, it doesn't have any effect on the outcome. I have edited my question with the dependencies I'm using.

Comment: @beatrice adding static solves the problem. But I'm not sure if this is the right solution since I have 2 instances from my filter? 1 in `web` and 1 in `security`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to the comment from `@dur`.

First I removed the `@Component` annotation so my filter doesn't get instantiated twice.

**Filter:**

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    private String test;

    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) {
        this.test = "TEST1234";
        System.out.println("TEST: " + this.test);

    }

    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("TEST: " + this.test);
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Also I have created the filter instance as a `bean` instead of calling `newFilter()` directly in the `addFilterBefore()` function.

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TestFilter testFilter() {
        return new TestFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(
                        testFilter(),
                        AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class
                );
    }
}
```

**Console output (now as expected):**

init: `TEST: TEST1234` doFilter: `TEST: TEST1234`